# Webservice call failing inside SQL Clr code due to SSL

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, ssl, sqlclr

I  am invoking a web Service call inside SQL Clr table valued function (C#).
When the sql function is invoked following error is received

"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

The web service url used is https and for SSL 3 i have explicitly used 
following directive in the C# code 
"ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;"

When the exact same C# codde is used in console application and invoked it works fine but from the SQL server its failing any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you perhaps closing or disposing of the connection ? perhaps it's a timeout issue.. post your code example that calls the webservice...thx

Comment: Declared as UNSAFE etc to allow it to do stuff that really shouldn't be done in SQL Server?

Comment: I fixed the issue ,  For sql server the certificate should be imported to Local machine certificate store , I did for the User store and this was stopping the underlying connection.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is fixed now,
For sql server clr web service code to use the certificate should be imported to Local machine certificate store , 
I did for the User store and this was stopping the underlying connection.